# Export BigCommerce Variant IDs

Tags: export-to-csv, bigcommerce

Is there a way for a user to export all variants with their IDs in BigCommerce?  After inspecting the built-in Bulk Edit template in Products -> Export, I don't believe it gives the variant IDs.  For rows with an Item Type of Product, the Product ID column shows the product ID.  But for rows with an Item Type of SKU, it appears to be showing a SKU ID rather than the variant ID.  I need the variant IDs to use the bulk update API endpoint to update variant inventory levels.

Comment: Hey Rachel, what api endpoint are you using to bulk update product variants? Can you share this?

Comment: Hi @HeatherBarr.  Thanks for your reply!  I'm using a PUT to /catalog/variants (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/variants/updatevariantsbatch).

Comment: You can definitely create a custom export templates if you feel it's not grabbing the values you're looking for. If you do this, re: create custom templates, and they aren't working for you --  I've confirmed with the developer who created https://bctools.io/ that you should be able to use their Products Download tool to grab the variant IDs via csv. I hope these options are helpful to you, let us know! Thanks Rachel.

Comment: Thanks, @HeatherBarr.  We actually just ended up pulling the IDs from the API and matching them up based on SKU.  It requires additional API calls, but it means the user doesn't have to deal with importing CSV files, so it will work for now.

Comment: Glad to hear you've found a workaround that works for you. :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.